# Does an equivalent LED bulb for an "inner bulb of an old incandescent E14 bulb" exist?

Tags: led, incandescent

### Update: question solved:

The bulb is a Gy6.35

### question

I have an old lamp with an incandescent bulb.

I would like to replace the incandescent bulb with an LED bulb, so I disassembled and photographed it (see photo), but I can't find a corresponding LED bulb, because I don't know what is the name of this model.

[image]

I went to an electronic shop and asked an employee what is the name of the bulb model in photo, and he told me that it is the "inner bulb of an incandescent E14 bulb", but he could not recommend me an equivalent LED model.

What's the name of the model bulb in the photo?

Is there a Led model with which I can replace it?

Comment: It is impossible to answer without more info. There os nothing that can tell the scale of measurements. What is the bulb voltage? What is the distance between the pins? What is the length of the pins? Did you google for "LED bulb socket types" and found a match?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please know, that questions on repair of items are off-topic. This socket type and filament appearance is typical for 12V halogen bulbs up to 35 W. But this might be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

What you have shown is an M11 bulb. You can find a guide to various types at [Lampco](https://www.lampco.co.uk/collections/2-pin-bulbs).

[image]

The shop assistant was probably describing one of these:

[image]

*Classic Bulb
The Classic Halogen Bulb is the standard Solus bulb, offering brilliant light from our Xenon Halogen Technology. It replaces the older traditional incandescent bulb. It lasts twice as long and consumes 30% less energy. Source: [Solas](https://www.solus.ie/which-bulb.html).*